# Visjs Dynamically Update a Timeline Item

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm using [visjs Timeline](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/), and I'm trying to have an item expanding from current time for a duration of 2 days.

```
var items = new vis.DataSet([{
  id = 0,
  start = moment(new Date()),
  end = moment(new Date()).add(2, 'days')
}, /* And maybe more items */]);
```

When creating a new timeline:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, null);
```

Now I want to update one of my items (say, the first one) so that it always starts from the current time. I thought that `currentTimeTick` would be a good place to update:

```
timeline.on('currentTimeTick', function() {
  var itemData = timeline.itemSet.items[0].data;
  itemData.start = moment();   // Set the start to current time
  timeline.itemSet.items[0].setData(itemData);
}
```

When I debug in Chrome, I see that the start time in the items set is changed, but I'm not sure why the UI isn't updated to reflect that change (I expect the start of the item to match my current time).

I went through the source code, and it seems to me that `setData` should cause a `redraw` on the timeline, but I don't think it's happening. When I drag the timeline, it causes a redraw and the item is sized accordingly. Do I need to do something to force a `redraw` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although calling `timeline.redraw()` is an option, it causes the whole timeline to be redrawn, which is expensive.

The [`RangeItem`](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/lib/timeline/component/item/RangeItem.js) has the method [`repositionX`](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/lib/timeline/component/item/RangeItem.js#L170) in its `prototype`, which apparently adjusts the horizontal position of the individual item, so what I did is to call this position after I set the data:

```
timeline.itemSet.items[0].setData(itemData);
timeline.itemSet.items[0].repositionX();
```

**EDIT**:
As @madebydavid suggested, instead of calling `repositionX` and `setData` directly, we can replace the two lines above with this single line:

```
timeline.itemsData.update(itemData);
```

Thanks @madebydavid

Comment: I think if you call the `update` method on the `vis.DataSet` it will trigger the redraw automatically. `timeline.itemSet.update(itemData);`. You do not need to call `setData` or `repositionX` that way.

Comment: Thanks you for the information. I will try it to see if it has the same behavior

Comment: I tried it, but it gives an error: `timeline.itemSet.update` is not a function

Comment: Ah yes, apologies - I usually manipulate the dataset directly rather than via the timeline. I think the correct function to call would be `timeline.itemsData.update()`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I think the `update` function here is expecting some arguments. I'm not sure what I need to pass to it.

Comment: You pass it the data for the item to update, so long as the data you pass has the id parameter the update function will change the existing record and redraw the block in the timeline. If you call update with data with a new id, a new block will be added to the timeline.

Comment: `timeline.itemsData.update(itemData)` - then you dont need to call repositionX

Comment: Thank you @madebydavid. I added your solution to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Did you try redraw the timeline?

```
timeline.redraw();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, the `redraw` function causes the whole timeline to be redrawn, which is costly. I ended up using the `repositionX` on the item itself

Answer (score 1):

Based on **version 7.4.2**, instead of `index i.e [0]...`, item `id` works:

```
// Get element from event
let element = e.target;

// Get item data
let itemData = prevTimeline.itemSet.items[element.id].data;

// Set end time based on the start time and duration
itemData.end = moment(itemData.start).add(moment(itemData.duration, 'HH:mm:ss').seconds(), 's');

// Update timeline data (auto refreshes)
prevTimeline.itemsData.update(itemData);
```